# How to deduct a delete in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a weird problem where data in a postgresql table gets cleared completely daily. I don't see any scripts or anything that runs the delete query. Is there a way i can find which script/process deletes the data from the particular table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to log the delete query even without restarting the server

Write a trigger function as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_delete() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RAISE LOG 'Deleting row % (statement is %)', OLD, current_query();
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Call the trigger function by

```
CREATE TRIGGER ondelete
  AFTER DELETE
  ON public.tablename
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.log_delete();
```

And that's it. your log will have the delete query that fired!
Ref : [Postgresql - Determining what records are removed from a cascading delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452778/postgresql-determining-what-records-are-removed-from-a-cascading-delete)

Answer (score 0):

You can see more about `log_statement` parameter. Set it to `all` so, all queries executed will be saved and you can do an analysis in what is happening with your database.

If you're on linux environment, the logs (normally) will be in `/var/log/postgresql/local0.*` files. And you can see what's happening.

Also, you can do more improvements on logs (like choose log only delete statements), as described on official documentation below.

More info at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html

You will need to restart you postgres to the changes take effect.